# Single PIN photodiode in comparision with dual PIN photodiode configuration of balanced detectors

Tags: photodiode, balanced

A typical balanced photo detector configuration to tackle background noise is depicted below:

[image]

There are configurations which use a new terminology and configuration like below:

[image]

Which configuration is much reliable when we try to remove background noise and detect low irradiance signals?

From my study so far, I understood the first configuration is better to cancel out background noise and also dark noise.  When is the second one used and where?

Comment: Please specify what "low irradiance signals" means in your situation. Are you thinking about nW/cm² or 100 mW/cm²? Alternatively please describe where the light is coming from and which detector in what distance is plausible for your project.

Comment: @datenheim the signal irradiance is in range of 1uW/cm2 falling on an avalanche photo diode

Comment: I should have asked for the photocurrent range... 1uW/cm2 is 10mW/m2... ddepending on spectrum and photodiode this could be few nA or uA, quite a difference.

Comment: Basically B) is the same as the first circuit. A) looks a bit strange, maybe you provide a more complete circuit example, as this looks a bit like working on photo voltage instead of photo current...